# How to make a list thats callable by an instruction displayed in another CSV

Tags: python, csv

I have two CSVs, one where the profiles are stored with the profile name naming each line and I want it to be a key in a dict like so: `profiles = {"profile1": ["item"]}` so I could pull the list of each profile / row.

Example of the CSVs

profiles.csv

```
PROFILE_NAME,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME
Profile1,John,Doe
Profile2,Jane,Deere
```

instructions.csv

```
PROFILE_NAME,JOB,HOURS
Profile1,Mechanic,50
Profile2,Cook,65
```

Code I have tried for storing rows as lists:

```py
    def info():
        file = "profiles.csv"
        with open(file) as f:
            reader = csv.DictReader(f)
            profiles = {}
            for row in reader:
                name = row['PROFILE_NAME']
                profiles[name] = [
                    row['FIRSTNAME'],
                    row['LASTNAME']
                ]
        return profiles
```

Comment: I don't quite understand... do you want merge the two CSVs into one?

Comment: So what is the purpose of `instructions.csv`?  Also `row['FIRSTNAME'], row['LASTNAME']` should be `row['FIRST_NAME'],row['LAST_NAME']`. Changing the column names made it work for me.